# How to iterate over Python dictionary keys

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary as follows. How can I iterate over all the values in the dictionary with matching first and second keys? for example iterate over all ('picture','angie',*) in the following dictionary

```
book = 
{('poem', 'jim', '1'): '$50', 
 ('poem', 'jim', '2'): '$51', 
 ('picture', 'angie', '1'): '$90', 
 ('picture', 'angie', '2'): '$10', 
 ('picture', 'angie', '3'): '$20'}
```

would return

```
 ('picture', 'angie', '1'): '$90'
 ('picture', 'angie', '2'): '$10' 
 ('picture', 'angie', '3'): '$20'
```

Comment: You should restructure your dict so you can access by key, iterating over the dict keys is defeating the main purpose of a dict,  there is also no first and second keys, each tuple is one key with three elements.

Comment: Padraic, how should the dict be restructured ? sorry I am new to python

Comment: what  are the 1 2, etc.. ?

Comment: 1, 2, 3 are unique page indices under 'picture' --> 'angie'

Comment: I added an example of how i would associate data,  treat "picture","angie"  as the author and associate the rest of the  data as values, treat a dict like a database, the primary key should allow you quick access. The fact you only care about the first row elements in the tuple should make it obvious what the key should really be. Using the logic on the answer below is an `O(n)` operation every time you want to do a lookup so you may as well use a list

Answer (score 3):

You could do that with `dict comprehension`:

```
res = {key: book[key] for key in book if key[0]=='picture' and key[1]=='angie'}

print(res)
{('picture', 'angie', '1'): '$90',
 ('picture', 'angie', '2'): '$10',
 ('picture', 'angie', '3'): '$20'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should restructure to something like:

```
book = {
 ('poem', 'jim'):[('2', '$51'), ('1', '$50')],
 ('picture', 'angie'):[('1','$90'),('2', '$10'),('3', '$20') ]}
```

Then doing a lookup would be a lot simpler and more efficient:

```
In [1]: book = {
   ...:  ('poem', 'jim'):[('2', '$51'), ('1', '$50')],
   ...:  ('picture', 'angie'):[('1','$90'),('2', '$10'),('3', '$20') ]}

In [2]: book["picture","angie"]
Out[2]: [('1', '$90'), ('2', '$10'), ('3', '$20')]
In [3]: book["poem","jim"]
Out[3]: [('2', '$51'), ('1', '$50')]
```

You can go further and create more relationships using subdicts, the main point is the outer keys should get you to common content, i,e an author with all their books av values, then if you wanted to go a step further you can categorise the books like:

```
 {"author_name1":{"horror":[..], "thriller":[...]},
 "author_name2":{"horror":[..], "thriller":[...]}}
```

Comment: this is awesome, thank you so much!

Comment: @CuongNguyen, no worries, like I commented above, treat a dict like a mini database,  your primary key should be unique and have no repeating data. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/first-normal-form.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
for key,value in book.iteritems():
    if key[0] == 'picture' and key[1] == 'angie':
        print key, value
```